# Can I install a fresh copy of Windows 10 for free on a new PC?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is it possible to download an offline installation and to install Windows 10 for free on a new PC without buying any previous versions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Windows is not free. You need to buy a copy if you want to install it on any PC.

(Technically, you *can* download a copy and install it, yes, but it will not be legal or licensed until you buy a license, this is the same as any previous version of Windows)

Comment: You _can_ continue the Insider route, it is legal. It won't be an activated version though and you will have to continue using Insider builds.

Answer (score -1):

I spent a bit of time looking into the matter.

You have two choices.

1. I looked into the [Windows Insider program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Insider) idea, as MC10 suggested in a comment above.  It looks like the Windows Insider program is still ongoing, even today, long after Windows 10 was released.  As long as you're willing to tolerate regular forced upgrades of newly-released Insider builds of Windows and regular forced Windows Update reboots, it looks like you can install the latest Windows 10 Insider Preview for free on your new PC.  But I'm not 100% sure of this.
2. Or you can install Linux instead.  The main advantages of Linux are threefold.  A)  You can install most (but not all) security updates without rebooting.  B)  You can upgrade almost all your software with a few clicks and no forced reboots.  C)  Linux's software-update tools can upgrade not just the OS, but also almost all your applications.

(On Windows, you can upgrade the OS and Microsoft Office with a few clicks.  If you want to mass-upgrade other software, you must use Chocolatey, which I feel is probably far less automatic than any Linux package manager.)

If you choose the Linux route:  If you're happy with older, stable software, I recommend Ubuntu LTS Edition; if you want more-frequent upgrades, I recommend Ubuntu.  But there are other good choices as well.

Comment: Only people with a Windows 10 license can enter the Windows Insider Program.  If you don't have a license then the Insider Preview build you install will nadir activate.  What does Linux have to do with the author's question?

Comment: @Ramhound: A) [This link](http://www.askvg.com/windows-10-offline-iso-now-available-for-download/) points you to Windows 10 Insider Preview ISOs and offers product keys. [This link](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-leave-windows-insider-program/) (s.v. "trial") warns you that, if you leave the Insider program, your Windows will be downgraded to trial status. Why do you think that the OP can't activate Windows 10 Insider Preview without a paid Windows license? B) Windows 10 Insider Preview may force frequent (and annoying) reboots. If the OP doesn't want these reboots, he can install Linux instead.

Comment: Those product keys do not activate unless you had previously activated then on hardware in 2015 before a specific date.  What makes me think what I said is Microsofts own words throughout the last year, my own experience testing Windows 10, and hundreds of hours of research in the subject